# ion-view view-title not centralizing

Tags: angularjs

I just create a new project and tested it:

```
ionic start test
```

In the browser, tha tag below works centralized as it´s ment to be, but in android 5.1 (lenovo A7010) it shows left aligned in Ionic view and compiling in apk.

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's by design. To override this setting do something like this:

```
var someApp = angular.module('yourSuperApp', ['ionic']);

someApp.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');
});
```

See [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/) for the documentation